# Overriding default screen contents in android

Tags: java, android

I am developing  a quiz app and my activity looks like this:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
         //click this button to go to the next question 
         mButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
         //open the DB
         openDB();

         //Check if the table has data
         if(!(myDb.checkDataExists())) {
             insertRows();
         }

         //display a random question

         displayQuestion();
    }

    private void displayQuestion() {  
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
        //check if number used or not
        if (isNumberNew(String.valueOf(randomNumber))) {   
            Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(randomNumber);
            displayRecordSet(cursor, optionAnswer);
            mOptionButton1.setBackgroundColor(color);
            mOptionButton2.setBackgroundColor(color);
            mOptionButton3.setBackgroundColor(color);
            mOptionButton4.setBackgroundColor(color);
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor, Map<String, String> optionAnswer) {
        int id = 0;
        String question = "", option  = "", rightAnswer = "";
        ArrayList<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storyImageView);
        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
        mOptionButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mOptionButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mOptionButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mOptionButton4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

}
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                 id = cursor.getInt(0);
                 question = cursor.getString(1);
                 option = cursor.getString(3);
                 rightAnswer = cursor.getString(5);
              optionList.add(option);
              optionAnswer.put(option,rightAnswer);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
            mOptionButton1.setText(optionList.get(0));
            mOptionButton2.setText(optionList.get(1));
            mOptionButton3.setText(optionList.get(2));
            mOptionButton4.setText(optionList.get(3));
        }
        cursor.close();
}
```

The displayQuestion method is supposed to get a random question from the db and then override the values of the option buttons and the question text view. However, when the app starts, the first question is still the one that I hardcoded in my view. In other words, when I call the setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz); ... I am putting default values in for the option buttons and the question text view. But, I don't want to display those values because they are just place holders. I want to display the question from the database, which I get through dipslayQuestion method.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be enough info to help you. What does displayRecordSet do and how are mOptionButtonX defined? Maybe you intended to change the text of buttons, not the background color?

Also, 2 things. Try to use more descriptive variable names instead of "flag" and such. Secondly, you shouldn't hardcode text into layout files you never want to use. Just set the text to "", you'll overwrite it anyway.